# how to show Text in PXSelector?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have taken a selector in formview, I was to show Text different and value is diffrent, because on click i want to redirect to detail form.

In my Graph PrimaryView is different. I have another view in Graph for example public  Detail. In DetailDAC has more then one property, I want to show Text in selector but when i click on link i want to redirect to detail form, what should i do?

If i show DAC key as DataField then on click, It redirect to detail.

For now, It is giving FormView doesn't exist error. if i set Text as DataField.

Comment: Can you provide code samples?  In general, you define the Primary Graph on the DAC, and then PXSelector takes you to that graph for navigation.  By detail, I assume you mean that you want to redirect to a specific tab/grid, but you need to redirect to the page by the key fields.  More detail, code examples, and pictures might give someone the ability to understand your issue and offer a solution.

Comment: public PXSelect<PrimaryDAC> PrimaryView;
 
public PXSelect<SecondryView,
          Where<SecondryView.pID, Equal<Current<PrimaryView.ID>>>>
          SecondryView;

   <px:PXPanel ID="PXPanel3" runat="server" RenderStyle="Simple" DataMember="SecondryView">
                <px:PXSelector ID="edID" runat="server" DataField="SecondryViewDisplayCD" DisplayMode="Hint" AllowEdit="True" CommitChanges="True" />
                </px:PXTextEdit>
            </px:PXPanel>

Comment: Thanks, user_mat.  You can edit your posted question and post your code there so that it is readable.  When including code in your question, be sure to prefix every line with 4 spaces so that it formats as a code box.  AllowEdit causes the PXSelector to navigate to the primary graph defined in the DAC for that field's table.  Can you also include your DAC - specifically the PXPrimaryGraph attribute on the class itself and the SecondaryViewDisplayCD field definition in the DAC?  (Best if you can post the whole DAC and just remove whatever fields you feel are irrelevant.)  I suspect a DAC issue.

Comment: After suggesting an edit to move your code to the original question, I see an unbalanced PXTextEdit tag.  I wasn't sure what you meant before about "text edit", but this tag should be removed, or relocated if it is the closing tag for a text edit somewhere higher up on the page.  It should be a structural issue in the page itself to have the unbalanced closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set DisplayMode=Text and use the selector like below

```
 [PXSelector(typeof(Search5<INSite.siteID, InnerJoin<EWQCSetupDetail, On<INSite.siteID, Equal<EWQCSetupDetail.warehouseID>,
      And<EWQCSetupDetail.locationType, Equal<QCQCLocationType>>>>, Aggregate<GroupBy<INSite.siteID>>>), typeof(INSite.siteCD), typeof(INSite.descr), SubstituteKey = typeof(INSite.siteCD))]
```